# Error 403 when calling the authentication in Office365 APIs of Azure AD

Tags: azure, office365

I'm making a web application to call Office365 API, and is using the authentication function of Azure AD. I am not having any progress since last week, and we suddenly got this error:

```
statuscode: 403,
body: '{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

Here is the Request that I sent

```
var request = {
    url: url,
    method: method,
    json: (method === constants.GET || method === constants.DELETE) ? null : resource,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': credentials.tokenType + ' ' + credentials.accessToken,
        'User-Agent': clientId,
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
}
```

Could anyone explain how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately this is an English language-only website and as such your question will be closed. Please ask the question in English if you are able.

Comment: Hi ORCD, Can you please provide your request URL or the resource you are hitting and the permissions you granted the app?  Thanks.